# What repetitions similar to "mero mero" exist in Spanish? That is, repetition of a word to convey additional meaning

Tags: vocabulario

I love the phrase *mero mero*, meaning *top banana* (e.g. "No pierdas el tiempo, pide cita de una vez con el mero mero").  I have a vague idea I know some more phrases like this, with the same word appearing twice, changing either the meaning or adding to it, but after a couple of days of letting this roll around in my mind, nothing is coming.

In addition to listing the phrase and explaining what it means, either in Spanish or English, please also include an example sentence and the country or region where you've heard it used, or the author and title if you learned it from a book.

Comment: Sorry it is not clear to me what _mero mero_ means, since I don't know what _top banana_ means either :)

Comment: Regarding the question itself, note that you are asking for a list of terms. As per now, it is a kind of question discouraged in [What topics can I ask about here?](/help/on-topic). We have been discussing this a bit lately, since good questions have emerged from it. The consensus so far is that we are  having a community wiki answer where people will include terms. This way, we won't have the problem of many answers, none of them is _the_ answer since they are not comparable.

Comment: @fedorqui - Sorry, it means the person at the very top, for example the branch manager of a bank. // Thanks for the guidance, but I didn't understand, does my question need editing?

Answer (score 6):

<sub>Find here some cases. Feel free to [edit](/posts/21063/edit) to add the ones you know.</sub>

---

- (Spain) *Este abrigo es de **piel piel***.

  - Meaning the coat is made of *good* leather.
- (Spain) *Ese restaurante es **caro caro***.

  - Meaning that the restaurant is *very* pricey.
- (Spain) *A mí esta pregunta me parece **rara rara***.

  - Meaning that the question is *really* weird.
- (Mexico)*Pide cita con el **mero mero***.

  - Meaning an appointment with the *real, overqualified* guy in charge (see *[mero](https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/mero#Adjetivo)*).
- *Esto es **café café**.*

  - Meaning it's *real* (non-ersatz) coffee.
- *Te he preparado un plato **rico rico** y con fundamento.*

  - Meaning the dish tastes *very* good.
- (Question): *¿Cómo te fue?* (Answer): ***Así así***.

  - Meaning 'so so', not good or bad.

Comment: Great start, thanks, could you say where you learned either each one, or all of them if it was the same region or country?

Comment: Yes, agreed with @walen. It is very common in Spain to repeat a word to add emphasis: _-¿Te gusta el fútbol? -Sí. -¿Mucho? -Sí, mucho mucho._

Comment: Most of these go for Argentina as well. *Así así* seems to be a calque from Italian *così così* with the same meaning; in Arg. it's *maso maso* (*maso* = *más o menos*).

Comment: @walen en el ejemplo de "mero mero" en lugar de **unqualified** creo que es todo lo contrario y significa `overqualified` ya que el _mero mero_ es el **más más**

Answer (score 0):

> **bien bien**

Ejemplo: Walen me contestó la pregunta *bien bien*.