# ¿Existe una expresión latinoamericana para "cortar el bacalao"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, expresiones, hispanoamérica, solicitud-de-modismo

Según [De dónde viene la expresión "cortar el *bacalao*"](http://blogs.20minutos.es/yaestaellistoquetodolosabe/de-donde-viene-la-expresion-el-que-corta-el-bacalao/)

> Esta expresión nos ayuda a designar y señalar quién es el que manda o
> toma las decisiones en un lugar determinado  y tiene su origen en los tiempos en el que el bacalao, salado y convenientemente  desecado, era uno de los alimentos más comunes, fáciles de adquirir y, sobre todo, transportar a otras partes del mundo; gracias a los largos periodos que duraba sin echarse a perder.
>
> Era común enviarlo hacia las colonias españolas repartidas en otros lugares del planeta (algunos países del Caribe y América del Sur, Filipinas y/o África).

Por lo que creo que así como está escrita es una expresión de uso en España. Yo creo haber escuchado una expresión parecida en Latinoamérica, pero que no usa la palabra "bacalao". ¿Existe una versión latinoamericana de esta expresión?

Comment: Supongo que "cortar el bacalao" sea una expresion equivalente a "el que lleva las riendas"

Comment: Aquí en Argentina se usa"cortar el bacalao" exactamente con el mismo sentido.

Comment: Exacto, @Theia ¿Cómo la decís en Cuba?

Comment: @fedorqui en Cuba se dice igual, "cortar el bacalao", aunque puedes encontrar otras expresiones como "tienes cogida la sarten por el mango", que es algo así como el que tiene el poder,(al menos en ese momento)

Comment: Gustavson, Theia, esas son respuesta válidas entonces ("se usa la expresión con el mismo sentido en Argentina/Cuba"; "Se usa 'tener la sartén por el mango' [que también se usa en España]"). Si sacáis tiempo ponedlas como respuestas en lugar de comentarios, por favor.

Comment: Gracias, Diego, pero por mí está bien así. De paso, aporto este enlace (hay varios más en Internet) sobre el origen de la frase: http://www.muyinteresante.es/cultura/arte-cultura/articulo/icual-es-el-origen-del-dicho-el-que-corta-el-bacalao

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Las siguientes son las expresiones utilizadas en hispanoamérica para designar a la persona "que toma las decisiones o que manda" equivalente a la expresión "el que corta el bacalao" usada en España.

- Argentina: El que corta el bacalao, [El que corta el estofado](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/21380/existe-una-expresi%C3%B3n-latinoamericana-para-cortar-el-bacalao/21392?noredirect=1#comment33431_21392)
- Colombia: El duro, El mandamás, La flecha
- Chile: [El que corta el *queque*](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/21391/11102)
- Cuba: El que corta el bacalao, [El que lleva las riendas](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/21380/existe-una-expresi%C3%B3n-latinoamericana-para-cortar-el-bacalao/21391#comment33403_21380)
- México: [El mero mero](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/21386/11102)
- Salvador: El mero mero

Comment: En Argentina algunos dicen "el que corta el estofado" https://www.google.com.ar/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=OmVZWayqNKKB8QeYpKywDg#q=%22el+que+corta+el+estofado%22

Answer (score 4):

No hace mucho, tuvimos [una pregunta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/21057/13628) que pedía ejemplos de expresiones que usasen la repetición de palabras para cambiar el significado de las mismas. Y como ejemplo ponía la expresión:

**[mero mero](https://www.google.es/search?q=%22mero+mero%22)**

Que por lo visto quiere decir "**el que manda de verdad**". Es usada en México y El Salvador, seguro; no sé si en otras partes de Centroamérica o Suramérica lo será también.

Answer (score 2):

En Chile decimos **[cortar el queque](https://es.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/cortar_el_queque?locale=es)**. Según la referencia que puse, también lo usarían los panameños.

Un *queque* es cualquier tipo de bizcocho o masa dulce (deriva del inglés  *cake*).