# ¿Cómo se llama al recurso sintáctico de duplicar un adjetivo para incrementar su valor?

Tags: gramática, sintaxis

En mucho lenguajes se puede repetir un adjetivo para incrementar su valor o añadirle ciertas connotaciones. Por ejemplo

> Viste a Laura en la fiesta? Estaba guapa *guapa*
>
> Sí que la vi. Con ese vestido rojo pero no rojo *rojo* si no un poco más como carmesí.
>
> Esa marca sí que hace esos productos buenos *buenos*
>
> Ya pero es que son caros *caros*, ¿eh?

En este Stack tuvimos la pregunta relacionada: [What repetitions similar to “mero mero” exist in Spanish? That is, repetition of a word to convey additional meaning](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/21057/5481) en la que se pueden ver otros muchos [ejemplos en la respuesta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/21063/5481) (cw).

Investigando, he visto que este recurso se llama en inglés [*Contrastive focus reduplication*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contrastive_focus_reduplication), también llamado *lexical cloning* o *double construction*. Pensaba que sabiendo eso iba a ser fácil verificar que en español se llama "clonación léxica", "doble construcción" o "foco reduplicativo", pero he tenido un sorprendente escaso éxito con mi búsqueda.

¿Puede alguien confirmar que en español recibe alguno de esos nombres o cuál es el correcto si es otro distinto?

Comment: Interesante pregunta. Me doy cuenta que esta tiene las etiquetas [tag:gramática] y [tag:sintaxis], mientras que [la de "mero mero"](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/21057/1674) tiene [tag:vocabulario]. Dado que son preguntas similares, la lógica nos dice que deberían tener etiquetas también similares. ¿Cuáles os parecen las más adecuadas?

Comment: @fedorqui - En la otra pregunta, yo no pregunté cómo se llama este aspecto de la lengua, así que creo que las etiquetas no tienen forzosamente que coincidir.  Sin embargo, me parece razonable agregar "vocabulario" o algo así a esta pregunta.

Comment: Pregunta relacionada: [Does Spanish have Contrastive Focus Reduplication?/ Tiene el español reduplicación de enfoque contrastivo?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/28799/5481)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Según ese artículo de la Wikipedia que enlazas, ese recurso es un tipo de [reduplicación](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduplicaci%C3%B3n_(ling%C3%BC%C3%ADstica)).

En este [estudio](http://www.raco.cat/index.php/EstudiGral/article/viewFile/43747/56177&a=bi&pagenumber=1&w=100) diferencian entre reduplicación léxica, morfológica y discursiva. El caso que nos ocupa sería *reduplicación léxica*, lo que me ha llevado a este otro [estudio](http://edizionicafoscari.unive.it/it/edizioni/libri/978-88-6969-080-8/la-reduplicacion-lexica-como-mecanismo-de-estrecha/) en el que hablan en concreto del fenómemo que planteas aquí (las negritas son mías):

> La **repetición léxica consecutiva**, denominada también **repetición
>   consecutiva** o **reduplicación léxica total** en la bibliografía en
>   español, consiste en la repetición voluntaria, contigua e idéntica de
>   palabras por un mismo emisor sin pausa significativa.

Y pone un par de ejemplos, este:

> (...) y de encontrarme por primera vez un restaurante **español español**
>   que no tiene nada de esas cosas de tome usted paella, (...)

y este otro:

> pero es que esto no es una **etiqueta etiqueta**

Buscando esos tres términos el que más resultados devuelve es *repetición consecutiva*, sin embargo muchos de esos resultados no coinciden exactamente con el tipo de reduplicación concreta de la que hablamos. *Repetición léxica consecutiva* solo me devuelve resultados del mismo estudio. En mi opinión *reduplicación léxica total* sería la mejor opción, hay pocas referencias pero coinciden con el recurso.

Comment: Olé por esta respuesta _buena buena_

Comment: Bien, @blonfu. Me gusta más "repetición" ("duplicación" pertenece más al mundo de las ciencias, me parece, y "reduplicación" me suena innesariamente redundante con ese prefijo, si no incorrecto).

Comment: @Gustavson Sí, suena raro pero se llama así: [reduplicación](http://dle.rae.es/?id=VaQTO4Q)

Comment: Otros casos de _reduplicación_ distintos a los de esta pregunta se dan en los siguientes ejemplos del habla inculta chilena: _no **te** vayas a caer**te**_, _¿qué **me** querís decir**me**?_