# Los verbos se usan como nombre

Tags: gramática

> —Gregoria habla con su prima Hilaría.
>   —¿Hablar, hablar? ¡No habla! Más bien canta.

No estoy seguro si puedo repetir el verbo “hablar” dos veces.

Comment: Discúlpame si he quitado los "gracias" de tus preguntas. Aunque parezca poco cortés, la razón por la que tratamos de evitar los saludos y las despedidas y agradecimientos en las preguntas es porque si queremos buscar la pregunta "Cómo decir gracias en español" o similar, aparecerán en la búsqueda todas aquellas preguntas que hayan dado las gracias pero que no tienen nada que ver con la pregunta que se busca. Lamento si así la pregunta parece más seca. En todo caso, sé bienvenido, y recuerda que cuantos más detalles nos des sobre tu duda, mejor podremos ayudarte. :-)

Comment: El nombre `Hilaria` no lleva tilde :)

Comment: La repetición del verbo es sólo para darle énfasis. "Hablar hablar" ~ "realmente, propiamente hablar". Más detalles: [aquí](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/28799/does-spanish-have-contrastive-focus-reduplication-tiene-el-espa%c3%b1ol-reduplicac) y [aquí](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/22028/c%c3%b3mo-se-llama-al-recurso-sint%c3%a1ctico-de-duplicar-un-adjetivo-para-incrementar-su/22030#22030).

Comment: creo que están confundiendo Hilaria con Hilaría

Answer (score 3):

> —Gregoria habla con su prima Hilaria.
>
> —¿Hablar, hablar? ¡No habla! Más bien canta.

Se puede repetir el verbo, y se lee todo seguido: *Hablar, hablar, no habla: más bien canta.*

Otra forma muy común de decir lo mismo es:

- *Lo que se dice "hablar", no habla: más bien canta.*

Nota: No diría que ese infinitivo está usado como sustantivo, sino que tiene un sentido casi metatextual. Sería sustantivo en frases como "su hablar pausado".