# Meaning of repeated "gente" phrase

Tags: género

I listen to Spanish radio and regular invitation/welcome message is "Buenas tardes a la gente gente." I understand the words (I think) but I cannot figure out the role of repeated "gente".

Comment: Hola, el asunto de la **reduplicación** ya ha sido discutido dos veces en este foro. Así que voy a tener que marcar la pregunta como duplicada, a menos que estés preguntando por otra cosa

Comment: Alternativamente: [¿Cómo se llama al recurso sintáctico de duplicar un adjetivo para incrementar su valor?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/22028/c%C3%B3mo-se-llama-al-recurso-sint%C3%A1ctico-de-duplicar-un-adjetivo-para-incrementar-su/22030#22030)